# How do I fully reset a custom AJAX object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have passed AJAX params all through a new object, then I pass this object to jQuery's `$.ajax()`.  What I am having problems with is trying to fully reset my object.  I mean I know there is a simple elegant way, I'm just not seeing it.  In fact, I think for now, I can't accomplish it at all.  Can some one pass along some help?

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing.

```
    var app{};

    var async = {};

    app.resetAjax = function(){
            app.async = {
                url: 'this/path/',
                dataType = 'JSON';
                type = 'GET';
            return app.async; //important, because i want to return it, this way. 
        }   
    };  

    //Then, come in later and set it up in another file
    async = app.resetAjax();
    async.type = 'POST';
    async.dataType = 'XML';
    async.headers : { ///defaults
        "SomethingWayWierd" : "hopeless", 
    };
    async.data = app.someOtherProp;
    async.timeout= 3000; //maybe one more tweak

    //then run the call somewhere
    $.ajax(async); //Now, this call MUST be XML, and the POST, not the default 'JSON' and 'GET'
```

So, notice, my function that resets, `resetAjax();`. This is my question.  How would I go about properly resetting it (i.e. gutting my reset function and replacing it with something suggested, more simple).  Could it be something as simple as

```
app.async = new $.ajax();
```

or maybe

```
app.async = $.ajax();
```

These are NOT working for me, they are failing, as is the way I did it originally in the original function.

So what's the right way to make sure that no previous settings are passed into my custom var called async, on the next go round, in a SPA?

I even tried this:

```
    app.async = {
        accepts: null,  //default: depends on DataType) Type: PlainObject
        async: true, //boolean, true by default, set to false if you want to send synchronously
        beforeSend: null, //Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject settings )
        cache: null, // (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
        complete: null, //Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
        contents: null,  //Type: PlainObject
        contentType: null, // (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
        context: null, //Type: PlainObject
        converters: null, // (default: {"* text": window.String, "text html": true, "text json": jQuery.parseJSON, "text xml": jQuery.parseXML})
        crossDomain: null, //(default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests)   Type: Boolean
        data: null, //{} //object, string ,array
        dataFilter: null, //Type: Function( String data, String type ) => Anything
        dataType: null, //'json', //'json', // string, what type of data do we want the server to send back?  there is no default on this, we can add one here if we need. JSON BROKE IT< DONT USE JSON AS DEFAULT
        error: null, //Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ),  DEFINED in app.router. rsvpAjax
        global: true, //boolean, defaults to true, set to false for prevent global handlers like ike ajaxStart or ajaxStop from being triggeredl
        headers: null, //(default: {}) Type: PlainObject
        ifModified: false, //boolean, defaults to false, if set to true then allow request to be successful only if the response has changed since last request
        isLocal: null, //(default: depends on current location protocol)  Type: Boolean
        jsonp: null, //Type: String
        jsonpCallback: null, //Type: String or Function()
        method: null,  //  (default: 'GET') Type: String
        mimeType: null,  //Type: String, A mime type to override the XHR mime type.
        password: null,  //Type: String
        processData: null,  //  (default: true) Type: Boolean //set to false if you want to send the form as a dom element
        scriptCharset: null,  //Type: String, Sets the charset attribute on the script tag, only applies when the "script" transport is used (e.g., cross-domain requests with "jsonp" or "script" dataType and "GET" type).
        statusCode: null,  // (default: {})  Type: PlainObject
        success: null,  // Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR ), DEFINED in app.router. rsvpAjax
        timeout : 10000, //10000 is 10 seconds //number,  app.router.ajax.timeout = null; //number,
        traditional: null,  // Type: Boolean, Set this to true if you wish to use the traditional style of param serialization.
        type: 'GET', // (default: 'GET') Type: string,  the type of request to make
        url: null, //  (default: The current page)  Type: String
        username: null,  //Type: String
        xhr: null,   //(default: ActiveXObject when available (IE), the XMLHttpRequest otherwise) Type: Function().  This is the callback for creating the XMLHttpRequest object.
        xhrFields: null  //Type: PlainObject, An object of fieldName-fieldValue pairs to set on the native XHR object. For example, you can use it to set withCredentials to true for cross-domain requests if needed.
    };
```

and will probably continue to get a trickling error effect, which it started by saying 'accepts:' can't be 'null', until I get all the settings dialed in correctly, and accounted for, which I don't want to maintain.  So, I feel like I'm needing `ajax.reset()` or something.

Comment: The initialization of `async` in function `resetAjax()`  is (i) global because it lacks `var` in front of it, and (ii) has a dangling comma and is missing a close brace `}` and (iii) `datatype` is declared as a separate global variable although I suspect you might want it to instead be a property of `async`.

Comment: @phari yes thanks, forgot to finish that one, corrected now.  and i think im done with all the major edits....  Note, this isnt a direct paste out of my actual file, so sorry for any typos, i.e. missing braces, those wouldnt be any issue, so anybody is welcome to correct them. ill see if i can find what you mention and fix it.

Comment: so instead of rewriting all of them individually (is there a place on the web that has this already), can i just run some "special" :-) ajax call that clears it out?  im getting things hanging over, and i cant determine if its my setting of async, or usage of ajax.  note these are global properties in my app that i didnt mention.  i.e. `app.async`, so i have it set initially as `app.async = {};`, but once the method is called to reset, its being molested and mangled  into something unusable, i.e. no longer a clean ajax param holder object..

Comment: Which settings are persisting?

Comment: `var async = {};` creates an empty object.  No need to clear anything.

Comment: Does that give you a better idea of how i use it?  i technically wrap it inside a parent function, but thats all design pattern.  all this is avoiding the question i think right?  or are you saying its related?  im just asking how i reset the entire thing to clean, zero, null, empty, so that the next time `$.ajax(async)` is ran, its not getting old stuff from a previous setting of async..  Mind you, this is all part of a reset method, so want a method to reset this for me, so next time around, i can run it again, i.e. `async = app.resetAjax();
app.async.dataType = 'text';
$.ajax(async); `

Comment: you know, thats a great question.  ill try to find out... , if i cant, then it means im explaining the usage a bit wrong, but still need a clean way to say `async = new $.ajax(); then async.url = '/yet/another/';`  i want my reset to be the `new $.ajax()` automator...  so ill see if i cant find that for you

Comment: By the way, i see i had a fundemental problem with the code e.g. in the OP.  So, i updated it.  See in the first i setup the reset method.  Then later in another file i use it. If i rinse and repeat the latter now, i get overbleed.

Comment: Wait a minute.... you mentioned global.  u might be onto something.  hoistage eh??? :-p i think i have a variable scope issue here maybe yes, on the part of async, which i just noticed in another part of the code, in a promise where i am $.extend this exact app.async object with.  I extend it with async right there when i instantiate a new promise.  so i think ill need to post that code.

Comment: Your method should simply destroy the previous instance of app.async and recreate it. That's a pretty uncommon way of running $.ajax though.

Comment: hmm, i think i found the problem, its in the following code snippet, the fix.  i WAS setting the var async globally, and it was being polluted...    now i moved it into the reset method... see below.  ill report back if this wasnt it.  but @paul made me think of this.  thanks.      This is my jquery ajax wrapper, and why im doing it different.y Katana314

Comment: `app.rsvpAjax = function (){
       var async,
        promise = new window.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){

            async = $.extend( true, {}, app.async, {
                    success: function(returnData) {
                        resolve(returnData);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        reject({ jqXhr: jqXhr, textStatus: textStatus, errorThrown: errorThrown});
                    }
                });
            $.ajax(async); 
        });
        return promise;
    };`

Comment: @paul are you going to put an answer or am I? lol.  It was the scope issue.  I wanted to paste my snippet into answer box though if anybody doesnt mind..

Comment: @BrianThomas If you have an answer, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code there is a hoisting issue going on, and a global problem.  If `async` were a property of `app`, then you reduce the scope.  Later, use it as the property, to reset it, then fine tune it, then call your ajax.

```
<?php 

var app{};
app.async = {};

//add your defaults here
app.resetAjax = function(){
        app.async = {
            url: 'default/path',
            dataType = 'JSON',
            type = 'GET', 
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
    }   
};  

//in your module adjust it when needed, then call it
app.resetAjax();
app.async.type = 'POST';
app.async.dataType = 'XML';
app.async.headers : { ///defaults
    "SomeWierdHeader" : "its value", 
};
app.async.data = app.someOtherProp;
app.async.timeout= 3000; //maybe one more tweak

//run it
$.ajax(app.async);
```